# How to define correctly unary operator- in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Suppose we have this class definition:

```
class A{
public:
    int a;
    A(int i): a(i){}
    A operator-() const { return A(- a); }     # first operator- function
};
A operator-(const A& o) { return A(- o.a); }   # second operator- function
```

Now, in the `main` function, if I write:

```
A a1(10);
A a2 = -a1;                # Here the first operator- function (method) is called!
```

However, if I remove the first definition of operator- in the class, the second function is called.
I would llike to know why the compiler prefers the first definition when both of them are provided.

I would like to know also why the compiler accept to call the first function (method). Because I think that the method is synonym to `a1-` and not `-a1` : The object on which the method is applied comes before (at the left of) the operator.

Comment: You might want to read more about [*unqualified lookup*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), especially how it works with [overloaded operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Overloaded_operator) and [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C++ [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), unary minus operator shall be defined like this:

```cpp
T T::operator-() const;
```

inside class definition, and like this:

```cpp
T operator-(const T &a);
```

outside class definition.

Now, you have both definition types in your class, so there member lookup comes in a play as specified [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> two separate lookups are performed: for the non-member operator
>   overloads and for the member operator overloads (for the operators
>   where both forms are permitted). Those sets are then merged with the
>   built-in operator overloads on equal grounds as described in overload
>   resolution. If explicit function call syntax is used, regular
>   unqualified name lookup is performed

So, basically, member lookup finds `A operator-() const;`, non-member lookup finds `A operator-(const A& o);`. Overload resolution selects `A operator-() const;`.